# MySQL Concatenate and Trim Data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns and basically I want to combine them into a fourth column and TRIM the data to less than 32 ?

I'm a little confused how to do this - basically I'm trying to do:

```
Column A - TEXT
Column B - Number
Column C - I need to Trim this to 10 chars and then use this Trimmed value
```

Column D = ColumnA + Column B + Column C

?

Edit:

So I'm trying this

```
UPDATE table
SET
  D = substring(concat(A, B, "|", substring(C, 0, 10)), 0, 32)
WHERE
  D IS NOT NULL
```

Will this work or ?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what trimming is ? It is only deleting space in end beginning and in the end of a string, it's not reducing a string length.

Comment: +1 - I actually want to reduce the string to only 10 chars from around 40 chars i.e. use the first 10 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this (untested)...

```
SUBSTR(CONCAT(ColumnA, Column B, Column C), 1, 32)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: @AllisonC thanks for the response :) Will this Trim Column C to use only 10 chars or ?

Comment: Sorry missed that part of the post. Try (untested): SUBSTR(CONCAT(ColumnA, Column B, SUBSTR(Column C, 0, 10)), 0, 32)

Comment: @AllisonC - added an edit to the q. Should this work ? I wanted to add a pipe-delimiter between B and C ?

Comment: UPDATE table SET D = substring(concat(A, B, "|", substring(C, 1, 10)), 1, 32); Note: I changed the 0 to 1...

Comment: @Tom the way you add functionnal requirement while developpers program reminds me the place where I work...

Answer (score 1):

Some useful MySQL functions for you:

- [TRIM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)
- [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [SUBSTRING()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

E.g.:

```
select substring(concat(A, B, substring(c, 0, 10)), 0, 32) from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, 
SUBSTR(CONCAT(TRIM(COLUMNA), TRIM(COLUMNB), SUBSTR(TRIM(COLUMNC),0,10), 0,32)
FROM YOURTABLE
```